# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error while printing the text from a div tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have the following problem: I want to get the text(Usa 982 310 para verificar tu cuenta de Instagram.)out of the css file with selenium and python:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="color:#666464;overflow:      
hidden;">Usa 982 310 para verificar tu cuenta de Instagram.</div>
```

MyPython code looks like this:

```
print(driver2.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[7]/button").text)
```

But I always get the error: TypeError:

```
'str' object is not callable
```

What should I do to fix this problem??

Answer (score 0):

The element:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="color:#666464;overflow:hidden;">Usa 982 310 para verificar tu cuenta de Instagram.</div>
```

is a **`hidden`** [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139).

So [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is unable to locate it and raises a [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294).

But you are trying to extract the *text* attribute of the string type object. Hence you see the error as:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

---

### Solution

You need to perform some action fist to make the `<tag>` visible i.e. remove the value `hidden` from the *style* attribute. Then you can retrieve the desired text.